# Generate n random variables whose sum will be 1

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a list which will contain some numbers whose sum will be 1. The code I am trying is:

```
listA = np.zeros(3)    
while(sum(listA) != 1):
        listA = container(np.random.rand() for _ in range(n))
```

However, this keeps running forever. The condition is: numbers have to be 0 or positive. Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: generate any 3 numbers, then scale them

Comment: Generate 2 numbers and calculate the third so that the sum is 1.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that you'll *ever* get precisely 1 from randomly choosing three floating point numbers, this is a very inefficient way to approach the problem.

Comment: How do you define "some numbers"? How many numbers do you want to generate? EDIT: Sorry, have not seen that you init listA with `np.zeros(3)`.

Comment: @khelwood can you demonstrate that this will have a uniform distribution?

Comment: @njzk2 Did the OP ask for uniform distribution?

Comment: @khelwood - what if my first two numbers are 0.5 and 0.75 ?

Comment: @Robᵩ then the third number is `-0.25`

Comment: I understood OP to want numbers in  `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ Well who knows. I'm going by what the question says (before it gets edited).

Comment: @Robᵩ: That's a fair assumption given that the OP's using `np.random.rand`. Hopefully, the OP will clarify...

Comment: Inspired by obligatory [xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/221/): `listA = [0.375, 0.5, 0.125]  # generated by fair dice rolls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
listA = [np.random.rand() for _ in range(3)]
scale = sum(listA)
listA = [i / scale for i in listA]
```

Comment: Except you need to add guard for `scale = 0` and redo, or perhaps just wrap in try-except

Comment: And of course, there's a good chance that the sum of `listA` won't be _exactly_ 1.0 after scaling, but I assume that's not an issue.

Comment: @njzk2, thank u. Thats working exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: Also, you can do `listA = [n*i / scale for i in listA]` where `n` is the final sum. I.E. `listA = [2.5*i / scale for i in listA]` may yield `[1.14757647227088, 0.6797194062558759, 0.672704121473244]`, the sum of which is 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be enough:

```
a = np.random.rand()
b = np.random.rand()
while a+b >= 1.0:
    b= np.random.rand()
c = 1.0 - a - b

listA = np.array([a,b,c])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create (n-1) random float numbers between 0 and 1. Sort them. Calculate the interval between 1 and the highest, the highest and the 2nd highest and so on. All the intervals summed up equal 1. There are n such intervals ( the interval between the lowest an 0 equals the lowest).

Update: Am I the only one who sees some serious problems with the scaling approach above?

Comment: What is the problem with the scaling approach?

Comment: The biggest problem would be that because of rounding issues (floats are discrete after all) the sum after scaling down would not neccesarily be the float closest to 1. So a (1.0 == sum) might not hold true.